# Update multiple rows in a single statment in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In SQLite I can execute multiple updates in a single statement by separating them with a semicolon:

```
UPDATE TABLEX 
SET x = 'y' 
WHERE a = 'b'; 

UPDATE TABLEX 
SET x = 'c' 
WHERE a = 'c'; 

UPDATE TABLEX 
SET x = 'd' 
WHERE a = 'v';
```

Can I do something similar in SQL Server?

The statements are being executed inside nodejs using tedious

Comment: Just use a seperate line for each statement

Comment: so I can seperate the statements as a single string by using a line feed ?? \n

Comment: sql server will not recognize your line feed syntax

Comment: you can also do what you're doing above with a single `update` statement with a `case` statement.  update tablex set x = case a when 'b' then 'y' when 'c' then 'c' when 'v' then 'd' else x end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. This is a valid sql statement for SQL Server. Separating each with a semi-colon (;) is the correct syntax. Hopefully, these are very independent changes on tables that don't have any dependencies on one another.

Any reason why you weren't able to test this for yourself?